# Why do I sometimes need to to add Nuget dependencies even if they're not used directly by my project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-4.0

Sorry for the vague title, but I didn't really know how to phrase it concisely.

Here's my problem: I have a .NET Framework C# solution that has 2 projects inside:

- `Project A`, a C# library which references Nuget package `NP`
- `Project B`, a C# application which includes `Project A` as a project reference

In `Project A`, I have a method like this:

```
public class FooClass {
    public static void Foo(){
        //does something with a class from referenced Nuget package "NP"
        NP.BarClass.Bar();
        return;
    }
}
```

In `Project B`, I call the above mentioned method, like this:

```
public static void main(){
    FooClass.Foo();
}
```

however, this gives the following compiler error:

> The type 'BarClass' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
>   must add a reference to assembly 'NP, Version=X.X.X.X,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx'

The solution, as suggested by the compiler, is to **also add a reference to Nuget package NP in Project B**. When I do that, everything works as expected.

My questions are:

- Why does this happen only with certain Nuget packages? I've been
  working with C# for a while now, and this doesn't happen with all
  packages, only some of them. For example, this time it's happening
  with package
  `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms`, but I've seen this happen with other nuget packages as well. However, with other packages this doesn't happen at all. For example, I've used package `ClosedXML` in the same project and it doesn't give me this problem. Why?
- Why does this happen at all? Since my project (`Project B`) is not
  directly referencing any types or methods from package NP, why do I
  have to include it explicitly? Isn't it enough that it's
  included in `Project A`, the one that uses it?

EDIT: I've managed to reproduce the problem in a self-contained example, see [here](https://github.com/tarockx/NugetInclusionDemo)

Comment: I see this with EntityFramework as well. I really hate how it violates encapsulation. Project B shouldn't need to know this much about how Project A works internally.

Comment: One possible reason is that Project B is not an SDK style project, and Project A uses PackageReference, rather than packages.config, to bring in the package.  Another possible reason would not cause the compiler error with the sample you provided. To create an answer explaining all possible reasons would take the effort of a large blog post, or maybe a multi-article blog series. Without more details about your specific example, I can't answer.

Comment: Was `NP` nuget package created by yourself? I did not find it in `nuget.org`. Also, what your VS version and specific framework version about these two projects?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT: that was just an example to make the question generic. It happened to me with various packages, the last one I had this problem with is `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms`

Comment: @zivkan: they both use `packages.config` to manage packages, not PackageReference

Comment: Are you sure that `ProjectA`'s `FooClass.Foo()` returns `void` and not `BarClass`?  If the return type is `BarClass`, that would explain the compiler error.

Comment: @zivkan: I simplified the example, my actual method returns a byte array (byte[]), but it surely does not return (or accept as parameters) any type defined in NP

Comment: In that case, I would expect that `ProjectB` should be able to compile without errors. Perhaps there were other methods/classes in ProjectA that you didn't notice returning `BarClass`?  Otherwise I'd need a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to investigate and provide an answer.

Comment: @zivkan: I seem to have found the source of the problem, see my answer. If you know the REASON behind it, feel free to comment, I still don't understand WHY this happens.

Comment: @zivkan: also managed to reproduced the problem, see the github link in my answer

Comment: Since you have a workaround about your issue, I suggest you could mark your answer so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues. Thanks:)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT: done, I was waiting because of the 24hour delay to confirm your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: I've reproduced the problem [here](https://github.com/tarockx/NugetInclusionDemo)**

Well, after further tiral-and-error, I finally found the source of the problem, and let me tell your: it's pretty weird, at least in my opinion.

So, the reason why this only seemed to happen in certain cases is because there seems to be a further requirement for this to happen. In particular, you have to have an **overloaded method with the same number of parameters that either returns or accepts as parameter a type from the nuget package in question**.

In my case, the `FooClass` in `ProjectA` was something like this:

```
public class FooClass
{
    public static void Foo(string x)
    {
        //Do something
        return;
    }

    public static void Foo(ClassFromNugetPackage np)
    {
        //Do something
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, in `ProjectB` I was only calling the first method, the one with the `string` parameter, but that was giving me the error, even if the project didn't directly reference any class from the nuget package.

However, if I rename the second method, so it is no longer an overload, like this:

```
public class FooClass
{
    public static void Foo(string x)
    {
        //Do something
        return;
    }

    public static void Bar(ClassFromNugetPackage np) //Renamed method
    {
        //Do something
        return;
    }
}
```

the problem disappeared!

If anyone can tell me the logic behind this, I would be happy. I mean, method overloading is resolved at compile time, right? The compiler should know I'm calling the version of the method that doesn't return/accept stuff from the nuget package... why the error then?

Comment: I don't work on the Roslyn team, so I'm guessing compiler internals, but since `ProjectB` calls `FooClass.Foo(T1)`. In order to determine that `T1` is `string` and not `ClassFromNuGetPackage`, it needs to do a type analysis of all overloads of the method, and in order to do that, it needs to be able to resolve all the types, including the one from the nuget package. When you call `Foo` with a string, maybe the compiler could theoretically avoid needing to analyse the other overloads. I did a quick search of the roslyn repo. I couldn't find an issue, but it's a hard topic to search for.

Comment: In the case where you call `Foo` with a type different to `string`, say I call `FooClass.Foo(1)`, the compiler needs to check if `int` is implicitly convertable to `string`, no, so now it needs to check if `int` is implicitly convertable to `ClassFromNuGetPackage`. Without having the assembly from the package to check for implicit operators, the compiler has no idea if your code is correct or not.

Comment: That's interesting. I would've thought that the compiler would know about `ClassFromNuGetPackage` anyway (since it's present in the other project, which in turn is included in the main one) and thus be able to understand that I'm calling the "safe" one, without the need for `ClassFromNuGetPackage` to actually be available in the project itself, but I don't know much about compilers so I guess there's a good reason if it can't figure it out automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen only with certain Nuget packages? I've been
>   working with C# for a while now, and this doesn't happen with all
>   packages, only some of them.

Since your issue is complex and we cannot test the whole in our side, maybe you can follow these:

**Actually**, it does have a possibility of conflict between your **VS Framework version** or **package reference format** and **the specific nuget packages**.

Some specific nuget packages are installed in the class library project, but when other projects refer to the class library, the content of some specific packages will conflict with the old framework version of the VS, so you still need to refer to the main The project can only be identified by adding this dependency. And this is just a problem with some special packages and framework version.

And another is just like **zivkan** said, you should keep package management format consistent(`Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`General`-->`Package Management`) to prevent conflicts due to different management formats. You should make sure that project A's output files including **NP** are in the Porject B's output files.

> Why does this happen at all? Since my project (Project B) is not
>   directly referencing any types or methods from package NP, why do I
>   have to include it explicitly? Isn't it enough that it's included in
>   Project A, the one that uses it?

I assume you used an old VS version(`<=VS2017`) to create such projects.

**In general**, you really don't need to include these in the main project(Project B).

**In fact**, In **VS2017** or **earlier**, in the form of **Project Reference**, there is indeed an issue that the dependent nuget and its files in the class library project will be lost in the project which references it. **Fortunately**, this problem has been fixed in vs2019.

So if your situation is what I said, I suggest you could use [the latest VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/).

**Or** in older VS version, use your solution--> add the nuget in Project B.

In my side with VS2019, I did not face the same error.

Comment: I'm using VS2019, but ProjectA was indeed created using VS2017. You seem to imply that might be the problem.. but is there a solution? Both projects are suing "packages.config" to manage packages btw. Also, I tried recreate a minimal example, but indeed the problem doesn't happen if I create the projects from scratch, it just happens in my existing projects

Comment: Well, I solved it... kinda. See my answer. If anyone has an explanation it would be great to hear it.